# Where do i put main address on this script to redirect eth to main address?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, tokens, contract-deployment

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
/**
 * Contract that will forward any incoming Ether to its creator
 */
contract Forwarder  {
  // Address to which any funds sent to this contract will be forwarded
  address public destinationAddress;

  /**
   * Create the contract, and set the destination address to that of the creator
   */
  function Forwarder() {
    destinationAddress = msg.sender;
  }

  /**
   * Default function; Gets called when Ether is deposited, and forwards it to the destination address
   */
  function () payable {
       {
          if (!destinationAddress.send(msg.value)) throw; 
      }
}
```

Let say for example my address where I want eth to be redirected to is 0x104ea4435b2ed36f36dc403b3638d82ec6a21bb7 but I am creating a contract from another address which I want the contract to redirect to address above. Where do I put it on the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the constructor instead of setting msg.sender as `destinationAddress`, use your actual address:

```
function Forwarder() {
        destinationAddress = 0x104ea4435b2ed36f36dc403b3638d82ec6a21bb7
      }
```

That should do.

Hope this helps